# ReactPHP FileSystem - No supported adapter found for this installation

Tags: php, reactphp

I'm trying to run this simple code on both PHP 7 and 8:

```
$loop = \React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$filesystem = \React\Filesystem\Filesystem::create($loop);
$file = $filesystem->file('test.txt');
$file->getContents()->then(function ($contents) {
    echo $contents . PHP_EOL;
});
$loop->run();
```

After [installing via composer](https://github.com/reactphp/filesystem), and yet it tells me that `adapter` is missing

Error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: No supported adapter found for this installation in \root\src\Filesystem.php:31
Stack trace:
#0 \root\try.php(6): React\Filesystem\Filesystem::create()
#1 {main}
  thrown in \root\vendor\react\filesystem\src\Filesystem.php on line 31
```

Comment: what is the exact error?

Comment: Could not reproduce your issue. 1) I installed the package and its dependencies using composer: `composer require react/filesystem:^0.1.1`, 2) Created a dummy `test.txt` file with a content, 3) And then I just added the `<?php` opening tag and `require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');` to the php script... After runnin the script, it printed the file contents correctly... Possibly an issue with your PHP installation, used libraries, etc.

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: No supported adapter found for this installation
@azibom

Comment: @PetrHejda I know how to use composer..

Comment: @iTaMaR Good for you. I was just telling you that using the information that you provided, I wasn't able to produce your issue, so possibly you might want to dig deeper and provide steps to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look where and why the exception originated. (I will use `react/filesystem:0.1.2` in code examples.)

The exception was thrown in `React\Filesystem\Filesystem::create()`. List of supported adapters is obtained from `React\Filesystem\Filesystem::getSupportedAdapters()`.

This way you will come to methods which define whether given adapter is available on your platform:

1. Method `Eio\Adapter::isSupported()`:
   `return substr(strtolower(PHP_OS), 0, 3) !== 'win' && function_exists('proc_open');`
   This means your platform must not be Windows and `proc_open()` function must exist (i.e. it must not be disabled for security reasons by [`disable_functions`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) directive).
2. Method `ChildProcess\Adapter::isSupported()`:
   `return extension_loaded('eio');`
   This means `eio` PHP extension must be installed, see [installation instructions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/eio.installation.php).

For me it also does not work as I am on Windows. For development with *ReactPHP*, it is generally a  good idea to run PHP on Linux virtual machine for better compatibility.